# Drag issue in d3.js v5.4.0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, draggable, drag

I am trying to implement [this](https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459) example using the `d3.js v5.4.0`.

But as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8kqoc0kf/) and here:[image]

The previous image of the node does not become deleted after the drag even though there is no error thrown.

I debugged the drag code stepping through the lines and was not able to find a reason for this. Will appreciate any help provided.

I thinks that the problem may be somewhere over here:

```
thisGraph.drag = d3.drag()
            .subject(function(d){
                return {x: d.x, y: d.y};
            })
            .on("drag", function(args){
                thisGraph.state.justDragged = true;
                thisGraph.dragmove.call(thisGraph, args);
            })
            .on("end", function() {
                // todo check if edge-mode is selected
            });
```

Comment: In your checklist you missed the most relevant part: **in the question itself**. That's why it's bold. And that's the reason your question was put on hold. Off-site resources can vanish, links can become broken, hence, you are required to put at least the relevant parts in your question. Another issue is that nobody wants to sift through 600+ lines of code in your JSFiddle. Keep in mind, that people offer their spare time to solve *your* problems. You should have made any effort that's in your power to make the problem as easily accessible as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Canvas? You need to run

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

each time it renders